# 405 Method not allowed in calling to WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I am calling using following request to a web service (copypaste from Chrome dev panel):

```
 Request URL:https://localhost:44300/api/userpreferences
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:51
 Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Host:localhost:44300
 Origin:http://localhost:3000
 Referer:http://localhost:3000/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
 Request Payloadview source
 {userName:asasa, projectId:2}
 projectId: 2
 userName: "asasas"
```

to a webservice method that has such a signatue:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public replyObj setCurrentProject(string userName, int projectId)
    {
    /// ... 
    }
```

as you see I followed interface in every detail. If I change method to PUT, other method is called with [HttpPut] attribute even if sugnature does not match, and this config just gives me {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
contrary to what I declared.

Comment: this may help : http://blog.dontpaniclabs.com/post/2013/01/23/That-Pesky-Requested-Resource-Does-Not-Support-HTTP-Method-POST-Error-When-Using-MVC-Web-API ..........System.Web.Http" and "System.Web.Mvc" have an "[HttpPost]" attribute use the "[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]" attribute

Comment: can you show your routes please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've faced with the same problem. It seems that your method signature doesn't match the route.
Change your method to

```
public replyObj setCurrentProject(dynamic value)
{
/// ... 
}
```

or you can use your appropriate class instead `dynamic`